# Metas OG Facebook - Sem reconhecimento da acentuação

Tags: facebook, html-meta-tag

Olá!

Em meu site, coloquei as metas og do Faceook, até ai tudo bem, o problema é que o título do site e as notícias contém acentos e ao compartilhar os campos com acentos não são exibidos.
Segue código utilizado:

```
 <?php
        if (isset($noticias_interna)) {
            foreach ($noticias_interna as $interna_noticias) {
                ?>
                <meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR">
                <meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
                <meta property="og:url" content="<?php print base_url(); ?>noticias/1/<?php print $interna_noticias->slug_noticia ?>"/>
                <meta property="og:title" content="Município de Itá - <?php print $interna_noticias->nome_noticia ?>">
                <meta property="og:site_name" content="Prefeitura de Itá"/>
                <meta property="og:description" content="<?php print $interna_noticias->lead_noticia ?>"/>
                <meta property="og:image" content="<?php print base_url(); ?>noticias/imagem_crop/<?php print $interna_noticias->imagem_noticia ?>"/>
                <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@o2multi">
                <meta name="twitter:title" content="Município de Itá - <?php print $interna_noticias->nome_noticia ?>">
                <meta name="twitter:description" content="<?php print strip_tags(character_limiter($interna_noticias->lead_noticia, 150)); ?>">
                <meta name="twitter:image" content="<?php print base_url(); ?>noticias/imagem_crop/<?php print $interna_noticias->imagem_noticia ?>">

                <?php
            }
        }
```

Por exemplo: o Título do site é Município de Itá, porém ao compartilhar fica Municpio de It

Alguém tem alguma solução para isto?
Lembrando que a meta charset está UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido, o problema é que o projeto foi feito por outra pessoa pelo programa Net Beans e os arquivos estavam salvos em formato ASC, somente salvei view por view em UTF-8 e resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Já tentou usar caracteres ASC II? Às vezes isso pode ser porque seu servidor não suporta alguns tipos de caracteres. Eu sempre uso ASC II para os acentos, aqui tem uma tabela com os códigos: https://www.codigofonte.net/dicas/html/30_tabela-com-codigos-em-ascii-para-seu-html

Tente substituir í por `&#237;` e á por `&#225;`

Comment: O problema é que o título da notícia é administrável, por exemplo, é cadastrado pelo cliente no painel administrativo, no compartilhamento ele pega direto do banco :/

Comment: Então não é o charset do banco o problema?

Comment: Não porque no banco também está em utf-8 :'(